# "TypeError: 'write' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". write is the name of my class

Tags: python-3.x

i have a method inside a class which returns some str value. i am initialising that class and calling that method of the class and i am getting the below mentioned error "TypeError: 'write_from_excel' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". 'write' is the name of my class

have tried everything

```
from xlwt import Workbook
import random
import string


class write_to_excel():



    wb = Workbook()

    # add_sheet is used to create sheet.
    sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

    def randomString(stringLength=10):
        """Generate a random string of fixed length """
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))


s = write_to_excel()
r = s.randomString()
print(r)
```

i expected the class to get initialised and run the method inside it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor to your `write_to_excel` class and pass in `self` to your `randomString` method for it to be recognized as an object method.

```
from xlwt import Workbook
import random
import string


class write_to_excel():

    def __init__(self):
        self.wb = Workbook()
        self.sheet1 = self.wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

    def randomString(self,stringLength=10):
        """Generate a random string of fixed length """
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))


s = write_to_excel()
r = s.randomString()
print(r)
```

output:

```
sakzsiuxwj
```

If you didn't want `wb` nor `sheet1` to be initialized, make your `__init__` method into this instead:

```
    def __init__(self):
        pass               #use only if you want an empty constructor
```

Comment: what if wb and sheet1 need not to be intialised ? would i still have to use the constructor ? if i have to use the constructor, what would i initialise in that case ?

Comment: @vigneshshrinivasan added an example